# Sencha Touch 2 MVC - How to pass/cache data between views and controllers

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch

There are multiple things unclear to me how data is best handled in Sencha Touch.

1 I'm loading data in a controller action from a Rest Store.

```
    Ext.ModelManager.getModel('MyApp.model.CheckIn').load(barcode, {
        synchronous: true,
        success: function(model) {              
            that.checkInConfirm({model:model});
        }
    });
```

Then the view gets updated by calling the corresponding setters of some fields e.g.
`this.getNickname().setValue(options.model.data.nickname);`
After this a view is activated with `this.getMain().setActiveItem(myView);` 
Is this the best way passing data from a controller to the view?

2 After manipulating data in the view another controller action is triggered by tapping a button. I then want to update the data loaded in 1. But at this moment my data I loaded before is lost. Do I have to load it again from the server or is there another way to preserve the previously loaded data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, that sounds good.
   The controller basically manages the data and sets it to your view(panel), which makes sense in MVC world. Just ensure that all bussiness logic (getting/updating/setting of data) is kept in your controller and is not placed in your view(panel).
2. Just store that options.model in your controller. Save it in yourController.models.yourModel or something similar.
   When you tap the button, it should dispatch an event to yourController. 
   yourController will then start manipulating its model and update the view with the updated model data.

Comment: Thx! Since it seems as there is no "Sencha Way" dealing with this problem I guess that's the way (or one way) to go. In my controllers init method I create an empty object called models which I use as you suggested for storing data.

Comment: That's how I do it too! I create an empty "models" and also an empty "views" object for it. Sencha 2 will also provide this functionality:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller
Additionally you can also create an empty "controllers" object for nested controllers.

Comment: Also, you can make your own CustomController derived from Ext.Controller that allows you to specify models, subcontrollers and views by its typename! In your constructor (which you have extended) you can then go over all the model names that are specified and instantiate them and assign them correctly so they are accessible by that name. This way you can easily attach models, views and subcontrollers to your controller by just specifying their name and you can access them just as easily.